# Is a Bet Din allowed to refuse to consider a case?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, civil-procedure

Frequently, in U.S. courts, a judge can decide not to hear a civil case if he feels that "it's a waste of the court's time" or he doesn't feel that there's sufficient evidence on either side, or various other reasons.

I gather that the smallest Bet Din consists of 3 judges. Can the Bet Din decide not to consider a civil case for any reason? Are there any limitations on what reasons they can use? And does the decision need to be unanimous among the 3 judges?

Comment: Bava Metzia 58b